# vue.js change php generated content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

Just started with vue, I have simple php echo on article title and i want to work with it in vue and change value for example.

```
<div id="app">
  <p><?php echo $title; ?></p>
</div>
```

Every example I have found used props and template, but it would force me to create html structure in js and alter the existing in html file, that I want to avoid.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/janheder/pen/oywpbW

This is what it would look like in jquery but I understand that vue works differently.

```
$('#app p').text("lorem ipsum");
```

Comment: VueJS power is in its data-binding you can use an XHR request to fetch the data from your PHP backend and then store that result inside a data property. Then display that property with `{{ someProperty }}`

Comment: You can use the existing HTML code as template for Vue, but the data you want to work with in Vue must either be passed to it or Vue must get the data itself. Using data from inside the HTML (template) contradicts how Vue works.